# ERROR: duplicate key violates unique constraint "search6_idx1"

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to insert items into my postgres table via PHP

But get the following error message `ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint "search6_idx1"`

search6_idx1 is the index table for search6. I tried the following `select setval('search6',45)` and somehow that only works for sequences.

Comment: if duplicate keys area allowed you should simply drop the unique constraint from your index ...

Comment: We need more information about this problem. Are duplicate values allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define an index you can optionally make it UNIQUE. Such indexes serve a double purpose:

- Speed up queries
- Prevent duplicates

In your case, it seems that the problem is one of these:

- You are inserting values that already exist
- Your index is UNIQUE by mistake

The respective solutions would be:

- Don't insert dupes
- Make a non-unique index